# Sync width of several elements with dynamic content in CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this component in my project

[image]

With this markup:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="title">
        PROJECT SETTINGS
    </div>
    <div class="column projectStats">
        <div class="statsRow">
            <span class="number">100</span>
            <span class="caption">Video Nodes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="statsRow">
            <span class="number">2</span>
            <span class="caption">Screens</span>
        </div>
        <div class="statsRow">
            <span class="number">2</span>
            <span class="caption">Paths</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant CSS:

```
.projectStats .number {
    border: 1px solid #05839E;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 1.1rem;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1rem;
}

.projectStats .statsRow {
    margin: 0.7rem 0rem;
}
```

As you can see, the "Screens" and "Paths" captions are misaligned with the "Video nodes" caption because of its value. I would like the width of the two circle elements (those with class `number`) to expand to the width of the widest number.
This - without setting a predefined width. The value is dynamic and can contain any number of digits.

For example - my desired outcome would look like this:

[image]

**Is there any CSS, non-javascript way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 4):

you may use display:table/table-row and table-cell:

```
.projectStats .number {
    border: 1px solid #05839E;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 1.1rem;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.projectStats .statsRow {
    margin: 0.7rem 0rem;
  display:table-row;
}
.column {
  display:table;
  border-spacing: 0 0.25rem ;
}
.caption {
  display:table-cell;
  text-indent:0.5rem;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLijA